# What is the proper reference designator for a ring terminal in a cable drawing?

Tags: cables, standard, drawing

I am working on some cable drawings that utilizes ring terminals that connect on a relay terminal. Initially, I was using T as the reference designator for them, but I realized that is incorrect since T refers to a transformer. I've looked online and couldn't really find a proper match for a ring terminal.

Would it be JP since I am creating a link?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: you could use   CN# for ring terminal